# AndroidStudioのクラス候補にpublicなstatic内部クラスが2つ出てくる件

Tags: android, android-studio

お世話になってます。
現在AndroidStudioを使いAndroidアプリを開発しているのですが、
publicなstatic内部クラスを定義しようとすると候補に同じクラスが2つ出てきます。
この場合の問題として何があるのでしょうか？
名前などを変えてみたり、他のクラスに定義してみましたが、同じような状態になりました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 単なるAndroidStudioのバグではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

バグです。JetBrainsのサイトにも報告されています：

[IDEA-139340 Inner class appears twice in code completion popup](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139340)

バグチケットに添付したスクリーンキャプチャはまったく同じ現象です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]